# How to get the name of the directory from the name of the directory + the file

Tags: python-3.x, string

In an application, I can get the path to a file which resides in a directory as a string:

```
"/path/to/the/file.txt"
```

In order to write another another file into that same directory, I want to change the string `"/path/to/the/file.txt"` and remove the part `"file.txt"` to finally only get

```
"/path/to/the/"
```

as a string

I could use

```
string  = "/path/to/the/file.txt"
string.split('/')
```

and then glue all the term (except the last one) together with a loop

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.basename` for getting last part of path and delete it with using `replace`.

```
import os
path = "/path/to/the/file.txt"

delete = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))
print(delete) # will return file.txt
#Remove file.txt in path
path = path.replace(delete,'')
print(path)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
file.txt
/path/to/the/
```

Let say you have an array include txt files . you can get all path like

```
new_path = ['file2.txt','file3.txt','file4.txt']
for get_new_path in new_path:
    print(path + get_new_path)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
/path/to/the/file2.txt
/path/to/the/file3.txt
/path/to/the/file4.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment @OmerTekbiyik. I upvoted your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally used

```
    iter = len(string.split('/'))-1

    directory_path_str = ""
    for i in range(0,iter):
        directory_path_str = directory_path_str + srtr.split('/')[i] + "/"
```